# Convergence of "continuous summation"

Tags: sequences-and-series

I don't know how to call the following object:

$$a + b(a + b(a + b( \cdots$$

For now I call it a "continuous function". I noticed that one can argue its value solving the following equation:

$$x = a + bx \Rightarrow x = \frac{a}{1-b}.$$

This seems quite surprising if you consider $a = 1,$ b = $2$. In this case, one gets $x = -1$!!!

How can the sum of positive numbers give a negative number as results?

**One approach of mine**

One can say that the result I'm looking for is the fixed point of a map defined as:

$$x_{n+1} = a + bx_n$$

If $a=1$ and $b=2$, the fixed point $x=-1$ is repulsive (or unstable if you prefer). It can be only reached by the map if and only if $x_0 = x = -1$. In this sense, it seems that:

$$1 + 2(1 + 2(1 + 2( \cdots = \lim_{n\to +\infty} \left.x_{n}\right|_{x_0 = -1} = -1$$

So it seems that the summation depend from the point you start, but this seems not really good to me...

Comment: This reminds me of $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty n  = -\frac{1}{12}$.

Comment: This is a naughty factorisation of a geometric series.

Comment: First, you can't argue like the way you're arguing. You are arguing about the "limit", but how are you so sure the limit exists? When you say: $x=a+bx$, you're saying that the *limit*, (when it exists), satisfies that equation.

Comment: the limit exists if $|b| < 1$ or if $x_0 = \frac{a}{1-b}$, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too long for a comment. Notice that your object is equivalent to 
$$a+b(a+b(a+b(a+..=a+ba+b^2a+b^3a...=a(1+b+b^2+b^3...)=a\cdot \frac{1}{1-b}$$
if $|b|<1$. In other words your mathematical object makes sense if $|b|<1$.

Comment: ok, that's make sense. Indeed, for $|b|<1$, the map always converges to $x = \frac{a}{1-b}$ for any $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$